# Not able to send push notifications in APNS Dev environment using Amazon SNS

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS service to send push notification.
But today, it suddenly stopped working.

I can't create another Application endpoint, it says - 
APNS Sandbox certificate is invalid

and I can't update credentials, the error is -
Request could not be completed (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalError)

I am able to send push notification using the same p12 file with another software i.e. https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

What could be the problem? 
How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: I am struggling with Push notifications for iOS Sandbox environment and AWS SNS too today. Seems that AWS SNS (http://status.aws.amazon.com) and Apples Sandbox (https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) are working though. Do you have any news on that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that (this is my guess) - I sent push notification with incorrect format.

That must have returned error code and because of that the connection between Amazon SNS to Apple server was closed. (It should be kept open always)
Because Apple thinks this as some kind of an attack.

The only remedy is wait for few hours and try again.

This is mentioned in the Technical Note here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same issue yesterday, it started working few hours back. can you confirm?

I spent whole day generating and testing certificates without any luck, and its working now with the same certificate.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing. Spent whole day generating certificate validating it. and the error from SNS wasn't helpful.
And it worked for me too after few hours.